Aligning multiple faceted plots with differing strip widths (with cowplot or another tool)
I am using ggplot with facet_wrap() and geom_rect() to create plots that have alternating grey/white stripes for the rows. I want to line up some of these plots using cowplot or another similar tool, but the differing widths of the "strip" on the left side of the plots is causing problems.
First, here's some code to do the general setup for a reproducible example. It creates four plots, "topleft" "topright" "bottomleft" and "bottomright":
library('cowplot')
library('ggplot2')

##### Set up data for the plots #####

set.seed(1)
varnames <- c('Label for the first variable','Here are some more words',
              'This is a third name for a thing','Another one','Short',
              'Also short','Short again')
ests <- runif(length(varnames),-0.6,0.6)
cibounds <- runif(length(varnames),0.01,0.1)
ORs <- exp(ests)
lower_cis <- exp(ests - cibounds)
upper_cis <- exp(ests + cibounds)
xrange_leftplots <- c(min(lower_cis),max(upper_cis))

rightvals <- runif(2*4 + 3*3,-0.25,0.8)
rightcibounds <- runif(length(rightvals),0.05,0.15)
right_lowcis <- rightvals - rightcibounds
right_highcis <- rightvals + rightcibounds
xrange_rightplots <- c(min(right_lowcis),max(right_highcis))

leftAdat <- data.frame(variable=varnames[1:4],val=ORs[1:4],lower_ci=lower_cis[1:4],upper_ci=upper_cis[1:4])
leftBdat <- data.frame(variable=varnames[5:7],val=ORs[5:7],lower_ci=lower_cis[5:7],upper_ci=upper_cis[5:7])
rightAdat <- data.frame(variable=rep(varnames[1:4],each=2),sex=rep(c('Female','Male'),4),
                val=rightvals[1:8],lower_ci=right_lowcis[1:8],upper_ci=right_highcis[1:8])
rightBdat <- data.frame(variable=rep(varnames[5:7],each=3),something=rep(c('Waffles','Leopards','Canada'),3),
                val=rightvals[9:17],lower_ci=right_lowcis[9:17],upper_ci=right_highcis[9:17])
rightBdat$something <- factor(rightBdat$something,levels=c('Leopards','Waffles','Canada'),ordered=T) # Prevents ggplot from putting them in a different order


##### Make the four chunks of the plot #####

# Function to make one of the four chunks of the plot
make_chunk <- function(dat,chunk_title,xrange,show_strip,stratby=NULL,strip_labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=20)) {
  # Set up for alternating gray/white strips
  variables <- sort(unique(dat$variable))
  dat$is_oddvar <- dat$variable %in% variables[seq(1,length(variables),2)]
  
  # Get the plot started with the right aes()
  if(is.null(stratby)) { # Unstratified, one point/CI per variable
    chunk <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=val,xmin=lower_ci,xmax=upper_ci,y=1))
  } else { # Stratified, multiple points/CIs per variable
    chunk <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=val,xmin=lower_ci,xmax=upper_ci,y=.data[[stratby]],color=.data[[stratby]])) +
      scale_color_discrete() # Prevent ordered factor from changing color scheme
  }
  # Add everything else to the plot
  chunk <- chunk +
  # Gray/white stripes
    geom_rect(aes(fill=is_oddvar),color='grey90',xmin = -Inf,xmax = Inf,ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks=c(T,F),values=c('grey90','white'),guide=NULL) +
    facet_wrap('variable',strip.position='left',ncol=1,scales='fixed',labeller=strip_labeller) +
  # Points and confidence intervals, plus a vertical line marking the null
    geom_vline(xintercept=ifelse(is.null(stratby),1,0),color='grey50',linewidth=0.25,linetype='dashed') +
    geom_point() + geom_linerange(linewidth=1) +
  # Other general things
    labs(subtitle=chunk_title) + theme_bw() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-1,7,0.5)) + coord_cartesian(xlim=xrange) +
    theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5),panel.spacing=unit(0,'lines'),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          legend.position='bottom',legend.title=element_blank(),legend.box.spacing=unit(0,'pt'))
  if(show_strip) {
    chunk <- chunk + theme(strip.text.y.left=element_text(angle=0))
  } else {
    chunk <- chunk + theme(strip.text.y.left=element_blank())
  }
  return(chunk)
}

topleft <- make_chunk(leftAdat,'Odds ratios',xrange_leftplots,T)
topright <- make_chunk(rightAdat,'Correlations stratified by sex',xrange_rightplots,F,'sex')
bottomleft <- make_chunk(leftBdat,'Odds ratios',xrange_leftplots,T)
bottomright <- make_chunk(rightBdat,'Correlations stratified by something else',xrange_rightplots,F,'something')

I can put the four plots together with cowplot and get them to align properly, but I end up with WAY too much white space between the left plots and the right plots:
plot_grid(topleft,topright,bottomleft,bottomright,ncol=2,rel_heights=c(4,3),align='vh',axis='tlbr')


Whatever is causing the excess white space appears to be related to aligning the left sides of the plots that have a strip - if I drop "left" from my alignment axes, the excess white space goes away (but the plots with a strip are no longer aligned on the left side):
plot_grid(topleft,topright,bottomleft,bottomright,ncol=2,rel_heights=c(4,3),align='vh',axis='tbr')


Ideally I would also like to add titles over the two horizontal pairs of plots, but if I do that I'll break alignment between top and bottom plots entirely:
plot_grid(
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("First set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
  plot_grid(topleft,topright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.5,1)),
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("Second set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
  plot_grid(bottomleft,bottomright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.5,1)),
  ncol=1,rel_heights=c(0.15,1,0.15,.9),align='v'
)


Setting margins on the left plots does not help, because the margin starts after the strip, and the strip still varies in width:
plot_grid(
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("First set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
  plot_grid(topleft + theme(plot.margin=margin(5.5,5.5,5.5,100)),
            topright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.5,1)),
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("Second set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
  plot_grid(bottomleft +  theme(plot.margin=margin(5.5,5.5,5.5,100)),
            bottomright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.5,1)),
  ncol=1,rel_heights=c(0.15,1,0.15,.9),align='v'
)


I tried an approach based on this StackOverflow solution that involves writing a custom labeller that adds an extra row of spaces to the bottom of the strip text to force it to meet a certain minimum width:
custom_labeller <- function(txt,width=20) {
  txt <- toupper(txt) # Make text uppercase to prove the custom labeller is processing the text
  # First, add line breaks for wrapping
  txtsplit <- lapply(txt,strwrap,width=width)
  with_linebreaks <- unlist(lapply(txtsplit,paste,collapse='\n'))
  # Add a row of spaces at the bottom to force a fixed strip width, and a blank line above to not break vertical centernig
  fixed_stripwidth <- paste0(' \n',with_linebreaks,'\n',paste(rep(' ',width),collapse=''))
  return(fixed_stripwidth)
}

topleft <- make_chunk(leftAdat,'Odds ratios',xrange_leftplots,T,strip_labeller=as_labeller(custom_labeller))
bottomleft <- make_chunk(leftBdat,'Odds ratios',xrange_leftplots,T,strip_labeller=as_labeller(custom_labeller))

plot_grid(
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("First set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
  plot_grid(topleft,topright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.5,1)),
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("Second set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
  plot_grid(bottomleft,bottomright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.5,1)),
  ncol=1,rel_heights=c(0.15,1,0.15,.9),align='v'
)


In the plot above I can tell my labeller is working because I made it make the text all-uppercase to show it did something, but the spaces I add seem to be getting automatically removed/ignored by ggplot.
I finally tried putting the strip in its own separate plot, and managed to produce results that are at least close to what I wanted:

The plot areas are aligned and approximately the same size
The titles for pairs of plots are centered over the plot areas (without including the left strip text in the area they're centered over)

title1 <- plot_grid(NULL,ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("First set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
                    nrow=1,rel_widths=c(0.37,2))
strip1 <- plot_grid(plotlist=get_plot_component(topleft,'strip',return_all=T),ncol=1) # Get strip labels, plot them as their own column
row1 <- plot_grid(strip1,topleft + theme(strip.text.y.left=element_blank()),topright,
                  nrow=1,align='h',axis='tb',rel_widths=c(0.37,1,1))
title2 <- plot_grid(NULL,ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle("Second set of things"),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold'),
                    nrow=1,rel_widths=c(0.37,2))
strip2 <- plot_grid(plotlist=get_plot_component(bottomleft,'strip',return_all=T),ncol=1)
row2 <- plot_grid(strip2,bottomleft + theme(strip.text.y.left=element_blank()),bottomright,
                  nrow=1,align='h',axis='tb',rel_widths=c(0.37,1,1))
plot_grid(title1,row1,title2,row2,ncol=1,rel_heights=c(0.15,1,0.15,.9),align='v')


But this plot still has some problems:

Too much white space between the strip text and the bottom left plot. (I don't want to right-justify the strip text because it will make labels that have a short second line like "Here are some more words" look weird.)
If I ever save the plot at different size/width, I will have to go back and manually adjust the relative widths for the strip columns again.

How can I fix the whitespace in the last plot, and automate giving the strip column the correct width when saving the image at different sizes?
(Additional details: I plan to make many sets of plots like this, so I prefer a solution that doesn't involve working out anything by hand for each plot. They will always be in pairs, but sometimes there will be more than two pairs, eg. some plots might have additional rows for "Third set of things" and "Fourth set of things".)

can you use patchwork in stead of cowplot? library(patchwork)
topleft + topright + bottomleft + bottomright + plot_layout(ncol = 2) seems to do what you want

@MichielDuvekot Thanks! Would patchwork have a way to add titles above the pairs of plots and still have the plot areas line up?

Yes, see plot_annotation()https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html

Hmm - it looks like plot_annotation() can only do a title for the overall four-panel plot or a tag for each panel, but not a shared title per two-panel pair like in my example. And the documentation says it will only work on the top-level patchwork, and that you can't annotate nested patchworks without breaking alignment. But I'm still looking into the design option of plot_layout() and wrap_elements(), it seems like there might be some way to use those.

Doing wrap_elements(topleft + topright + plot_layout(ncol=2) + plot_annotation(title='First set of things',theme=theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16,hjust=0.5)))) + wrap_elements(bottomleft + bottomright + plot_layout(ncol=2) + plot_annotation(title='Second set of things',theme=theme(plot.title=element_text(size=16,hjust=0.5)))) + plot_layout(nrow=2) adds the two titles, but plots that should be in the same column are no longer aligned.

With layout <- "###AAAA###\nBBBBBCCCCC\nBBBBBCCCCC\nBBBBBCCCCC\nBBBBBCCCCC\nBBBBBCCCCC\n###DDDD###\nEEEEEFFFFF\nEEEEEFFFFF\nEEEEEFFFFF\nEEEEEFFFFF\nEEEEEFFFFF" and textGrob() from library('grid'), I can do wrap_elements(textGrob("First set of things")) + topleft + topright + wrap_elements(textGrob("Second set of things")) + bottomleft + bottomright +  plot_layout(design=layout) and get the plot I wanted!! I still need to figure out other things cowplot could do like shared legends if both plots in a pair are stratified and doing this all programmatically, but I think this might work!

After a lot more research, I have a solution to my question.
This is a general solution to the problem "my ggplots have differing amounts of space to the left of the panel" (whether that's due to strip labels, y-axis text, a legend, etc.). It can be used for making nested multi-plot layouts when nesting breaks your preferred tool's ability to align plots. If you're not using a layout tool you can also just use it to make multiple plots that have consistent space to the left of the panel.
This solution uses the libraries gtable and grid to calculate the total width to the left of the panel for each plot, find the maximum across all plots, and calculate how much space needs to be added to each plot to make them match. It then adds that space to the left margin of each plot. (It adds to the left margin, not the strip width - making the strip artificially wide would lead to strange text alignment for plots with short strip labels, like the last example in my question. Adding space to the left margin instead lets all plot elements keep the width that looks normal for that plot.)
Here is code that takes the plots from my reproducible example in the question and gives plots with strips a consistent total width to the left of the plot panel:
library('gtable')
library('grid')

# Put things in lists so I can use lapply or loops
leftplots <- list(topleft,bottomleft)

# Turn plots into gtables
left_gtabs <- lapply(leftplots,ggplotGrob)

# Have a look at one of the plots visually to figure out which column is the main plot
# Since my plots have the same basic layout, it will always be the same column, but this may vary for yours
gtable_show_layout(left_gtabs[[1]]) # The strip is the 7th column, the main plot is the 8th

# This function gets the total width to the left of the panel
# It loops over the width of gtable columns until one has a unit of "null" (eg. is probably a main plot panel)
# It adds up these widths, and return the total in units of "points"
get_left_widths <- function(gtab,output_unit='pt') {
  total <- unit(0,output_unit)
  for(i in 1:length(gtab$widths)) {
    if(unitType(gtab$widths[[i]])=='null') break # Found a main plot panel
    total <- total + convertUnit(gtab$widths[[i]],output_unit)
  }
  return(total)
}
# Current width to the left of the panel for each plot
left_widths <- lapply(left_gtabs,get_left_widths)
# Maximum space to the left of the panel for any plot
max_left <- unit(max(as.numeric(left_widths)),'pt') 
# How much needs to be added to the left of each plot for a consistent width?
add_left <- unit(as.numeric(max_left) - as.numeric(left_widths),'pt') 

# Now add that extra space to the left margin of each plot
# This loop assumes all plots have their margins in the default margin unit "points"
# If yours don't, add unit conversion here with grid::convertUnit()
for(i in 1:length(leftplots)) {
  plot_margins <- leftplots[[i]]$theme$plot.margin # Get the original plot margins
  plot_margins[[4]] <- plot_margins[[4]] + add_left[[i]]
  leftplots[[i]] <- leftplots[[i]] + theme(plot.margin=plot_margins)
}

There are multiple places in the code above where I remove units using as.numeric() and then add them again with unit(), eg. unit(max(as.numeric(left_widths)),'pt') and unit(as.numeric(max_left) - as.numeric(left_widths),'pt'). What I'm doing there is removing the units so I can treat the list of measurements with units like a vector of numbers (to do something like subtract or take the maximum), then putting the units back on when I'm done. As an alternative, I also could have looped over the lists instead of removing the units to temporarily treat them as vectors. Loops are the safer option when you don't know what the units in your list will be, eg. the loop I used in the get_left_widths() function.
Once my code above has added the necessary space to the left margin of each plot, I can do a complicated nested multi-plot layout with almost any tool without having to worry about alignment any more. (This works with almost any layout tool because I applied the modification to the original ggplot instead of the gtable). To demonstrate, here is how I could finish my original example plot with cowplot:
library('cowplot')

# Give titles for plot pairs the same "area to the left" I calculated for plots, so they'll center correctly over plot pairs
title_margin <- theme(plot.margin=margin(0,0,0,max_left))

plot_grid(
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle('First set of things'),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold') + title_margin,
  plot_grid(leftplots[[1]],topright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.4,1)),
  ggdraw() + draw_label(ggtitle('Second set of things'),hjust=0.5,size=16,fontface='bold') + title_margin,
  plot_grid(leftplots[[2]],bottomright,nrow=1,align='h',rel_widths=c(1.4,1)),
  ncol=1,rel_heights=c(0.15,1,0.15,.9)
)


Hopefully this generalized solution will be helpful to other people looking for information about alignment issues in nested multi-plot layouts. For anyone who finds this answer while searching but needs more information for their specific situation, I would suggest reading this fantastic page from the egg package about plot alignment and the general ecosystem of plot layout tools and then possibly looking into the gtable package which gives you tools to get into the guts of a ggplot's layout.
