Wrap ggplot2 strip text in a way that avoids short final lines?
I am making a plot where variable descriptions appear in the left "strip" text of facet_wrap() facets. Sometimes when variable descriptions are long enough to be wrapped, the last line comes out very short. This can make the plot look weird, especially if the text is right-justified.
Here's a reproducible example:
library('ggplot2')

dat <- data.frame(variable=rep(c('Frogs','Kittens wearing tiny hats','Mars',
          'Really long name that will wrap to three lines','Tacos',
          'Your local public library'),each=2))
dat$stratify <- rep(c('Yes','No'),6)
dat$beta <- 1:12
dat$lower_ci <- dat$beta - (1:12)/10
dat$upper_ci <- dat$beta + (1:12)/10
dat$is_oddvar <- grepl('Frogs|Mars|Tacos',dat$variable) # Every other variable in the plot has a grey stripe

ggplot(dat,aes(x=beta,xmin=lower_ci,xmax=upper_ci,y=stratify,color=stratify)) +
  # Gray/white stripes
  geom_rect(aes(fill=is_oddvar),color='grey90',xmin = -Inf,xmax = Inf,ymin = -Inf,ymax = Inf) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c(T,F),values=c('grey90','white'),guide=NULL) +
  facet_wrap('variable',strip.position='left',ncol=1,scales='fixed',labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=24)) +
  # Points and confidence intervals
  geom_point() + geom_linerange(linewidth=1) +
  # Themes/general plot appearance
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.spacing=unit(0,'lines'),panel.border=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.left=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1),strip.background=element_blank(),
        legend.position='bottom',legend.title=element_blank())


Is there a way to make the labeller split lines more evenly when they're long enough that they need to be wrapped? For example, to wrap "Kittens wearing tiny hats" as "Kittens wearing | tiny hats" instead of "Kittens wearing tiny | hats"?

This is related to my other (very long) question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78986965/aligning-multiple-faceted-plots-with-differing-strip-widths-with-cowplot-or-ano , but that one is about multi-plot layouts. Rather than make that one even longer, I put text-wrapping in its own standalone question.

I found out that nchar() can be used to control the length of the strings of the labeller. Since nchar() returns the number of characters of the input strings, we can use facet_wrap() variable as its input strings, and then divide its return with a fraction to get a numeric vector of lengths. Then, we use this vector as the value of width in label_wrap_gen().
In your example, by trial and error I found 0.51 is a good choice. I then changed your facet_wrap(...) line to the following:
facet_wrap(vars(variable),strip.position='left',ncol=1,scales='fixed',
             labeller=label_wrap_gen(width = nchar(vars(variable))/0.51))

Here is the result:


I have tested and it works, upvote. But I find it counter intuitive, to divide by a fraction makes the numbers bigger. By dividing by 0.51 you are praticaly doubling nchar's return values. Can you elaborate on your explanation of the reason why your answer works?

Unfortunately, as for now, I don't know why it works. It is indeed counter-intuitive because label_wrap_gen documentation says it uses base::strwrap() for line wrapping, while in strwrap() we get more lines with smaller width, which is intuitive.

Looks like the expression vars(variable) is handed over as an unevaluated expression ~variable. "~variable" has 9 characters. So it's not the label(s) determining the wrapping width but the constant 9/.51, approximately 18, which agrees with the line break after "Really long names" (17 chars).

One approach with {ggtext}:

    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggtext)
    
    data.frame(variable = c('Frogs','Kittens wearing tiny hats','Mars',
                            'Really long name that will wrap to three lines','Tacos',
                            'Your local public library')
    ) |> 
      ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(1, 1)) +
      facet_wrap(~ variable, strip.position = 'left', ncol = 1) +
      theme(strip.text = element_textbox_simple(maxwidth = unit(1, 'in'),
                                                halign = 1,
                                                margin = margin(0, 5, 0, 0)
                                                ),
            strip.background=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_blank()
      ) +
      labs(x = '', y = '')



Note that {ggtext} also allows to render markdown, incl. HTML. So one should be able to use the whole works of CSS text wrapping and aligning (haven't tried though).
